# What is this symbol and how do I recreate it in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

This "I" symbol used in matroid notation:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, it can be generated by `\mathcal`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathcal{I} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: You have been very fast. I gave the approval of his first post. I think your question is probably a duplicate of some other question on the site. However, the vote positively like the others of yours.